# How do I delete photos uploaded to Dropbox via Camera Upload?

Tags: dropbox

I experimented with Dropbox's Camera Upload feature from my Android, do not wish to keep using it, and now wish to delete the approx. 2000 images and videos now occupying space on Dropbox.  How can I do this?

Comment: "Camera Uploads" is just a folder. Can you not simply delete it?

Comment: I believe that in Dropbox, it is a "persistent" folder that comes as part of the service

Comment: @AlEverett I think the answer is actually no. I have deleted all the files from my Cameraupload folder and they are still present if I check the web interface of Dropbox. Unintuitively, another step is required.

Answer (score 9):

Sign in to Dropbox. From the Dropbox webpage: go to the "Camera Uploads" folder and click on the ones you want deleted. (You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to highlight all on that page.)

Then click on "delete" in the top menu.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

I merely created a new folder in my 'Pictures' folder (on PC) beside the open Dropbox 'Camera Uploads' folder and highlighted all the pics/videos I wished to remove and dragged/dropped them into my Pictures folder. Worked fine.